# How to get multiple route using Google API

Tags: ios, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using following url in for getting routes

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=17.4444,78.4666&destination=17.4393,78.4056&units=imperial&alternatives=true&sensor=false

I need to show several paths between two destinations as we see on google maps.
so Problem is when i request firstly i get more than one route in response afterwards when I change destinations it gives only one route.

kindly help on same.

Comment: you want to get all the route that google give you or just the best one?

Comment: all routes, and what is the other possible values for request parameter 'units'?does it make sense?

Comment: I tried the url you provided above and it always returns 3 paths(routes). I didn't see the situation where it only give one route.

Comment: "afterwards"? After what?

Comment: edited my question.. I think it should be more meaningful now